# video system not initialized, is there trouble with my graphic card or my code

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know if the problem is from my graphic card unable to run the program or the code is wrong.

My code is:

```
import pygame
import sys

class AlienInvasion:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("ALien Invasion")

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.quit():
                    sys.exit()

            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pygame\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    ai.run_game()
  File "C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\pygame\main.py", line 17, in run_game
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Comment: have you tried `pygame.init()` ?

Comment: Please consider accepting answers when they solve your problem (checkmark on the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the test `if event.type == pygame.quit():` you are actually
quitting pygame by calling the `quit` function of the module.  Hence
the `pygame.display.flip()` naturally raises an error after that.

What you meant is probably:

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

where you compare the event type to the `QUIT` constant.